# angular2 with angular material does not have any effect

Tags: angular, angular-material

I followed all the instructions as given here: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

However no material style is being applied.

In my index.html:

```
  <!-- material theme -->
  <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

in module.ts:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then I have a component template as:

```
<form>
    <!-- title -->
    <md-input-container>
        <input md-input placeholder="Title">
    </md-input-container>
    <!-- Description -->
    <md-input-container>
        <input md-input placeholder="Description">
    </md-input-container>
    <!-- priority -->
    <md-select placeholder="Priority">
        <md-option *ngFor="let priority of priorities" >
            {{ priority }}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <!-- tags -->
    <md-chip-list>
        <md-chip>UI</md-chip>
        <md-chip>Performance</md-chip>
        <md-chip>Design</md-chip>   
    </md-chip-list>


</form>
```

However looks like there is no theme applied, chips do not look like chips and there is no color basically.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: open console/network tabs, let's check your `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` loaded correctly

Comment: yes it is not loaded correctly. Why? The path looks correct

Comment: did you using angular cli or another seed, if you using angular cli, just import it because angular cli won't serve node_modules folder https://youtu.be/0q9FOeEELPY?t=3m50s

Comment: yes I am using cli, I just added @import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css'; in styles.css. and now it looks fine!

Comment: great, i'm using cli, but with scss, it's great tool.

Comment: Alternatively you can put a relative link to the stylesheet in the `styles` array in `angular-cli.json`.

Comment: Okay! thanks a lot! I find material lite much easier to use than this, although it does not have all the components ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide for Angular CLI:

choose the theme you wanna use: indigo-pink, deeppurple-amber, pink-bluegrey, purple-green.

**update beta.3**

**styles.css**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.c‌​ss';
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink';
```

===================

**styles.css**

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.c‌​ss';
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink';
```